# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. (I have used the Key still getting this error)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As i have used the Key still im getting this error.

```
<>
            <h1>Latest Products</h1>
            {loading ? (
            <h2>loading...</h2>
            ) : error ? (
             <h3>{error}</h3> 
            ) :  
             <Row>
                
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                       
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>}

        </>
```

What is the problem here and how to solve it.

Comment: try `{products.map((product) => { console.log(product) return ( <Col key={product._id}> </Col> ) })}` to see full list that is rendered

Comment: sure I tried this and on my console i was getting the products array and also the error

Answer (score 0):

I think product._id is undefined so for all the array elements the value is the same. Please console the product._id.

Comment: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] after logging it im getting the array in console but when i try to render it its not showing

Comment: can you please show the value of the products array. you can show it by console.log("products", JSON.stringify(products))

Comment: {
        "rating": 4.5,
        "numReviews": 12,
        "price": 89.99,
        "countInStock": 10,
        "_id": "609584c01fa8d0331c41deeb",
        "name": "Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
        "image": "/images/airpods.jpg",
        "description": "Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-quality AAC alls while working",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "category": "Electronics",
        "user": "609584bf1fa8d0331c41dee8",
        "reviews": [],
        "__v": 0,
       
    },

Comment: array has 6 objects with different (._id)

Comment: Please try 
     {products.map((product, index) => (
                    <Col key={index} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                       
                        <Product product={product} />
                    </Col>
                ))}

Comment: if above doesn't work then try to use key value as : key = {product._id.toString()}

Comment: yes as suggested above the error is gone but the rendring problems still stays the same

Comment: it would be better if you can share your repository.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else pointed out, the `product._id` is probably `undefined` or not a unique value (which is pretty bad in itself). You can fix the error by appending the `index` to the `product._id` value:

```js
<Row>
  {products.map((product, index) => (
    <Col key={`${product._id}-${index}`} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
      <Product product={product} />
    </Col>
  ))}
</Row>;
```

Comment: when i tried this the error was gone but the worst thing happened is that the product also disappeared from chrome screen

Comment: can you post a function which is loading the products?

Comment: const Product = ({ product }) => {
    return(
        <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
            <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
                <Card.Img src={product.image} variant='top' />
            </Link>
            <Card.Body>
            <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
               <Card.Title as='div'>
                    <strong>{product.name}</strong>
  </Card.Title>
</Link>
<Card.Text as='div'>
<Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.rating} stars`} /></Card.Text>
<Card.Text as='h3'>
${product.price}
</Card.Text>
</Card.Body></Card>)}

Comment: Im literally kinda new to react so if I commented wrong do tell me pls ty

Comment: import axios from 'axios'
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST }
       from '../constants/productConstants'


       export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

  const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')
dispatch({   type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
 payload: data })
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message,
})}
}

Comment: router.get(
    '/',
    asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const products = await Product.find({})

        res.json(products)
    })
) this is the route for fetching products